# Property Setter: Making Added/Subtracted/Incremented value available inside property scope

Tags: c#, properties, encapsulation, setter

**Goal:** In my property setter, I need to sometimes multiply the added/subtracted/incremented value to another variable.

For example, if I do the following code:

```
MyProperty+=1;
MyProperty++;
MyProperty-=1;
```

In my setter, I need that 1 to be available so I can multiply it to my value:

```
    int myField;
    public int MyProperty
    {
        get
        {
            return myField;
        }
        set
        {
           int variable = variableThatContainsTheOne * otherVariable;
           myField= variable;
        }
    }
```

I currently am implementing a separate function setter but that is sloppy. And cant use the built-in "value" because that will be simply the updated "myField".

**My questions are:**

(A) Is there not a way to get that 1 by some built in value like "value"?

(B) Is there a creative way that you know of where I can encapsulate this into the property setter?

(C) Any way to know whether someone tried to increase, decrease, or set the value? (Encapsulated within the setter or property scope)

Comment: Instead of using a number litteral, e.g. 1, why not use a variable that your setter can reference?

Comment: @Ian Yes, I thought of that but would be sloppy/non-encapsulated, too. I would have to create that variable, change it, in its setter do the logic with multiplying, then set the result to the MyProperty.